# CPU usage of Oracle installed Database machine

Tags: linux, database-design, unix, spring-mvc, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g and i have an application which is coded in Spring framework. Once i configure the database on Sun fire 4170 installed with Linux the machine's CPU utilization is around 80-100% and, however, when i shift the same database to Sun M3000 server installed with Unix OS (supposedly more powerful machine) the application performance goes down and CPU utilization remains 90-100%. I can't figure out if its the application which is making the such utilization or its the database design. 
It is added that the database is not relational; things are handled by the application.

Comment: Can add some `sar` statistics, with process is taking the CPU...

Comment: Oracle is an RDBMS. Using it with a framework like Spring will have dramatic impacts on performance. Spring makes coding faster, not databases. I guarantee you'll find a lot of iterations over every row, one-at-a-time. At least, that's what I've found when looking at databases built by programmers who use frameworks.

Comment: "I guarantee you'll find a lot of iterations over every row, one-at-a-time." Can you please brief me about this. ...I have been developing applications in JSF framework with hibernate and i have always been using Oracle RDBMS as my database and so far i have not confronted such sort of problem. JSF is also a framework then why Spring is posing such problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you certainly can find some interesting opinions on the intertubes.

> Oracle does not have a true server
>   architecture (others have it).
>
> Rather than performing classic server
>   tasks, such as multi-threading,
>   caching of data pages, parallel
>   processing (split a query across many
>   devices) etc. within itself, it uses
>   the o/s to do all that. That means for
>   each user process (PL/SQL connection)
>   there is one unix process; 1000 users
>   means 1000 unix processes, all
>   competing for the same resources.

You might note that Oracle has had

- a connection pooling architecture (multi-threaded server) since version 7 (1992).
- a cache for data pages (known helpfully as the buffer cache) since forever
- parallel query (splitting a query across many processes) since version 7.1 (1993)
- splitting queries across multiple servers since OPS (version 6) or across distributed databases (version 5)

It's also noteworthy that even if all that was said was correct rather than incorrect it doesn't actually help you in determining root cause.

> Especially noteworthy, because it uses
>   file system files (not raw
>   partitions), and the "caching" is
>   outside, it relies heavily on (and is
>   very sensitive to) the file system
>   cache that you have set up. likewise,
>   Oracle needs a massive amount of
>   memory for these processes.

Oracle certainly can use raw partitions again dating back to the last millenium, moreover if you wish to cache within the database - using the buffer cache that PerformanceDBA has forgotten about - and bypass the filesystem cache this feature is available on all current filesystems. Oracle also supplies it's own combined filesystem/volume manager in ASM which you can use if you wish.

Oracle is also rather well instrumented (and if you have access to dtrace so is solaris) and can certainly tell you what sessions, processes etc are using the CPU, what the time the application spends in the database is consumed by (down to individual block read times if you care) and so is very susceptible to profiling. I'd recommend that you check out Thinking Clearly about Performance available at http://www.method-r.com/downloads/cat_view/38-papers-and-articles and written by one of the top Oracle Performance experts in the world. If you have access to the Oracle Diagnostics pack then checking out first of all ADDM reports and secondly AWR reports would be profitable.

Comment: Thank you, Niall. I think this is a great comment, not precisely an answer to the questioner but a refutation of an existing answer. I believe my comment above is most likely the true issue. I've never seen a framework app perform well.

Comment: 1) Exactly.  It ihas nothing to do with the question, just a major rant about another answer.  My post is directed at helping the seeker for the existing oracle problem, not arguing what kind of non-architecture Oracle is. 2) Why flag RPs that no one ever uses ? 3) Oracle is "well-instrumented" only if you have no experience with true server architectures such as Sybase or DB2 in the last 25 years. dtrace is evidence of **no instrumentation** or monitoring or diagnostic info, and thus **having** to use o/s utilities.

Comment: PerformanceDBA hates Oracle with a passion only matched by his total ignorance about it.  He should either educate himself about Oracl;e or shut up about it IMO.

Answer (score 6):

Trying to avoid a flame war here.

I should probably have separated out the "how to find out" part of my response more clearly from my responses to the comments about server architecture from PerformanceDBA. I share Stephanie's suspicions about the spring framework, but without properly scoped measurement evidence there is no point in blaming any particular attribute of the environment, that would be just particular bias. Fortunately the instrumentation built into the oracle kernel allows you to trace and then profile the slow sessions to determine exactly where the issue lies. So I would do the following:

1) enable tracing for a representative session (you can use the dbms_monitor package for that). 
2) also gather an execution plan for the statement(s) involved with the gather_plan_statistics hint. 
3) profile the trace file by time using an appropriate profile (tkprof,orasrp,method-r profiler)

Investigate the problem statements in contribution to response time order.

If you can't carry out the above, then you can use ADDM and/or AWR if licenced as I originally suggested or statspack if not licensed for the diagnostics pack. ADDM naturally concentrates on time consumers, I suggest if you are forced down the statspack route you do the same.

Answer (score 4):

> The M3000 is certainly a more powerful machine, but it is more suitable for true servers. The X4170 with hyper-threads is more suited for file servers.

I'm not so certain about that.  Have any data to support that claim?

An M3000 has one SPARC64 VII processor with 4 cores ([tech specs](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/035939.pdf)) while a X4170 has 1 or 2 Intel 5500 "Nehalem-EP" processors each with 4 cores ([tech specs](http://www.sun.com/servers/x64/x4170/specs.xml)).  I know that I would expect much more from even a single processor Nehalem-EP system, than the M3000.  Obviously data will vary slightly with the workload, but I know where I'd put my money.

Comment: This is a horses for courses issue, question, answer. In discussing the apprpriateness of an M3000 vs X4170 specifically for Oracle, and explaining why it performs better on the latter. If he had Sybase, being a true server architecture, it would perform better (than oracle, not better overall) on the M3000. It is impotant to appreciate that point, otherwise the discussion is meaningless (we are not merely comparing two machines out of context).